# Calculate the total cost between two dates based on a weighted time interval scheme

Tags: c#, datetime

Consider we have to pay the usage of a machine with the following hourly cost:

- 00:00 - 01:00 --> $4 per hour
- 01:00 - 05:00 --> $1 per hour
- 05:00 - 22:00 --> $2 per hour
- 22:00 - 24:00 --> $3 per hour

If we use that machine from a date of `x` to another date of `y` with the given weighted time interval `w`,

```
var w = new List<Tuple<TimeSpan, double>>
{
    new Tuple<TimeSpan, double>(new TimeSpan(1,0,0),1),// hourly cost is 1 from 01:00 to the next boundary
    new Tuple<TimeSpan, double>(new TimeSpan(5,0,0),2),// hourly cost is 2 from 05:00 to the next boundary
    new Tuple<TimeSpan, double>(new TimeSpan(22,0,0),3),// hourly cost is 3 from 22:00 to the next boundary
    new Tuple<TimeSpan, double>(new TimeSpan(24,0,0),4)// hourly cost is 4 from 00:00 to the next boundary

};
```

the following is my attempt at calculating the total cost between two dates based on a weighted time interval scheme. Please kindly review it and make it much better.

```
class Program
{
    // x cannot be later than y.
    // the TimeSpan of w must be in ascending order

    static double Total(DateTime x, DateTime y, List<Tuple<TimeSpan, double>> w)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        int days = (int)(y - x).TotalDays;

        if (days > 0)
            sum += Sum(new TimeSpan(), new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0), w) * days;

        sum += Sum(x.TimeOfDay, y.TimeOfDay, w);

        return sum;
    }

    // x may be later than y.
    // the TimeSpan of w must be in ascending order

    static double Sum(TimeSpan x, TimeSpan y, List<Tuple<TimeSpan, double>> w)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        if (x > y)
        {
            sum += Sum(x, new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0), w);
            sum += Sum(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0), y, w);
            return sum;
        }


        w.Insert(0, new Tuple<TimeSpan, double>(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0), w.Last().Item2));

        for (int i = 0; i < w.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (x >= w[i + 1].Item1)
                continue;
            else
            {
                for (int j = i; j < w.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (y >= w[j + 1].Item1)
                    {
                        if (i == j)
                            sum += (w[j + 1].Item1 - x).TotalHours * w[j].Item2;
                        else
                            sum += (w[j + 1].Item1 - w[j].Item1).TotalHours * w[j].Item2;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i == j)
                            sum += (y - x).TotalHours * w[j].Item2;
                        else
                            sum += (y - w[j].Item1).TotalHours * w[j].Item2;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        w.RemoveAt(0);
        return sum;
    }


    static void Print(DateTime start, DateTime stop, List<Tuple<TimeSpan, double>> w)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"x = {start:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:fff  tt}\ny = {stop:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:fff  tt}\ncost = {Total(start, stop, w)}\n");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var w = new List<Tuple<TimeSpan, double>>
        {
            new Tuple<TimeSpan, double>(new TimeSpan(1,0,0),1),// hourly cost is 1 from 01:00 to the next boundary
            new Tuple<TimeSpan, double>(new TimeSpan(5,0,0),2),// hourly cost is 2 from 05:00 to the next boundary
            new Tuple<TimeSpan, double>(new TimeSpan(22,0,0),3),// hourly cost is 3 from 22:00 to the next boundary
            new Tuple<TimeSpan, double>(new TimeSpan(24,0,0),4)// hourly cost is 4 from 00:00 to the next boundary
        };


        Print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 30, 0, 1), new DateTime(2016, 1, 2, 0, 30, 0, 0), w);
        Print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 30, 0, 1), new DateTime(2016, 1, 3, 0, 30, 0, 0), w);

        Print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 1, 2, 22, 59, 59, 999), w);
        Print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 1, 3, 22, 59, 59, 999), w);

        Print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), w);


        Print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0), w);
        Print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 1, 2, 22, 0, 0, 0), w);

        Print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), w);
        Print(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), w);

    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Your 'Question' is off-topic, we can review the rest.

Comment: instead of your `Print` function calls use unit tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Create a Class for the DateTime pair**

Make the constructor ensure the pair is in the correct order and the "x > y" type code goes away.

And the constructor will check for null, strip milliseconds, etc. Client code can then presume clean data.

Override `CompareTo` so sorting to proper order is trivial. And even more code goes away.

This class should contain its own `Sum()`

---

**Create a class for the List of DateTime pairs**

This class will keep its elements in order. More code goes away.

This class should contain its own `Sum()`.

---

**Variable Names!**

The sheer complexity of `Sum` demands meaningful variable names.

---

**Ambiguous Weighted Ranges**

Is exactly 1 hour charged at $1/hr or $2/hr? Ditto for 5 and 22 hours. What about more than 24 hrs?

Don't say "just read the code." I'll just say the code is wrong, or the documentation is wrong. I can't tell which.

---

**'rithmatic**

Use `decimal` for money calculations. [A quote of a quote from an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/693373)

> The Decimal value type is appropriate for financial calculations requiring large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors. The Decimal type does not eliminate the need for rounding. Rather, it minimizes errors due to rounding.

Display results consistently.

Comment: For ambiguous Weighted Ranges: See the output at the end, one year cost is presented.